# How to do the export and import of object (map object) in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, openlayers-3, es6-modules

I am having RAS_MapComponent class and this will display the openlayers map with some defaulted linestring in the map.

I want to test the defaulted linestring coordinates in another class.So, I need to pass the `map` Object to my test class from RAS_MapComponent class. I have tried to export the map Object using `props` and it is throwing an error.

How can I export the map object from the main class (`RAS_MapComponent`) to test class ()?

I am getting an error in the below line in test class

```
 var maplayers=MapComponent.map.getLayers();
```

**Main Class:**

```
class RAS_MapComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    var raster=new Tile({
      source: new OSM()
    });
    //Location A - Latitude and Longitude
    var coords1 = proj.fromLonLat([79.2652587890625,19.532871485421026]);
    var iconFeature1 =new Feature({
      geometry: new Point(coords1),
      name: 'Marker 1' });
   //Location B - Latitude and Longitude
   var coords2 = proj.fromLonLat([81.24279785156249,18.02679570052561]);
    var iconFeature2 =new Feature({
        geometry: new Point(coords2),
        name: 'Marker 2' });

   var lineBetweenTwoFeatures =new Feature({
          geometry: new LineString([coords1, coords2]),
          name: 'Line between markers',
        });

    var source = new SourceVector({
      features: [iconFeature1,iconFeature2,lineBetweenTwoFeatures],
      wrapX: false
    });

    var width = 3;

    var vector = new LayerVector({
      source: source,
      style: [
        new Style({
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: 'white',
            width: width + 2
          })
        }),
        new Style({
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: 'red',
            width: width
          })
        })
      ]
    });

   var map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [raster,vector],
      view: new View({
        center: proj.fromLonLat([78.8718, 21.7679]),
        zoom: 4
      })
    }) 
    map.getView().fit(source.getExtent());

  }

  render() {
    return (    
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    )
  }
}

export default RAS_MapComponent;
```

**Test Class:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import MapComponent from "./components/RAS_MapComponent";

it('Check the Long and lat from map',()=> {

  var maplayers=MapComponent.map.getLayers();

  maplayers.forEach(function(layer) {
    if(layer instanceof LayerVector){
      var features = layer.getSource().getFeatures();
      features.forEach(function(feature) {
        console.log("Features Coordinates :"+proj.toLonLat(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()));
     });
    }
  });
});
```

**Error:**

```
export default _ol_;
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/RAS_MapComponent.js:4:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:4:25)
```

**Node Version :** v8.10.0
**Package.JSON:**

```
{
  "name": "react_spa",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "d3-chart": "0.0.1",
    "ol": "^4.6.5",
    "ol-contextmenu": "^3.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-chartjs": "^1.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-minimal-pie-chart": "^3.0.2",
    "react-ol": "^0.1.12",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "recharts": "^1.0.0-beta.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-openlayers": "^0.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like babel transform issue. Can you share your node version? Also can you share you package.json file?

Comment: @Harkirat Saluja :Node Version is v8.10.0 and package.json is updated in the question